# Transform all variables into lowercase shell

Tags: shell

I have this small snippet in my script:

```
    scriptVars="ProjectEnvironment ProjectType Project SubProject sshUser"
    for scriptVar in $scriptVars
    do
        # Transform all uppercase letters into lowercase
        $scriptVar=${!scriptVar,,}
    done
    echo $ProjectEnvironment
```

I'm trying to force only lower case characters on the variables.
Alas, it doesn't allow me to perform this - it errors that it's not a command.
My guess is that it's becuase I'm in a loop, and it sort of acts like a local variable only inside the loop.

Is there anyway to set it so it would work?

It might be obvious, but it's worth to mention the variables are prompted by the user.

### EDIT 3.11.12

I ended up using this, by using @chepner answer:

```
    scriptVars="ProjectEnvironment ProjectType Project SubProject sshUser"
    for scriptVar in $scriptVars
    do
        [[ -n `echo ${!scriptVar} | tr -d "[:lower:][:digit:]-"` ]] &&
        declare "$scriptVar=${!scriptVar,,}"
    done
    echo $ProjectEnvironment
```

only alpha-numeric and dashes are allowed in the variables (I have a previous sanity check for that), thus only if the variable have uppercase letters does it redeclare it.

Comment: Remove the sigil ($) when assigning the $scriptVar variable.

Comment: Yep, that almost does the trick. Now I only have to find out how to move the variable outside the loop as well...I read this as a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122454/curious-problem-for-vs-while-read-loops-and-visibility-of-variables-in-shel but it didn't help much...Outside the loop it's still uppercase.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to force lowercase right after the prompt? Something along the lines of $ read {sshUser,,}?

Comment: in ksh you can declare your variable to be lower case only, ie. `typeset -l my_lc_var`, I think there is a similar feature in bash. Good luck.

Comment: typset -l is available in bash and zsh, but either I couldn't figure out how to use it, or I don't know what. It doesn't prompt me to enter a value in the command line, nor does it transform to lowercase later on. Could you elaborate on this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indirection only works on the right-hand side of an assignment, not the left-hand side. You'll have to use the `declare` keyword as well.

```
scriptVars="ProjectEnvironment ProjectType Project SubProject sshUser"
for scriptVar in $scriptVars
do
    # Transform all uppercase letters into lowercase
    declare "$scriptVar=${!scriptVar,,}"
done
echo $ProjectEnvironment
```

Another approach is to use a proper array, since you can apply expansions to all elements at once without an explicit loop.

```
values=( "$ProjectEnvironment" "$ProjectType" "$Project" "$SubProject" "$sshUser" )
values=( "${values[@],,}" )
ProjectEnvironment=${values[0]}
ProjectType=${values[1]}
# etc.
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second option? I tried it and it seems I have to redeclare all the variables yet again, whereas in the loop I can add a conditional statement to only redeclare it if the variable have upper-case letters (see edit above). And what is the meaning of a "proper" array? I thought all arrays in bash are not "real" arrays...

Comment: In your original, you don't have an array; you have a string that consists of space-separated words. A "proper" array can be indexed, as shown in my second example (`${values[1]}`). The second approach would be cleaner if you didn't have to reset the value of each variable, but could instead just access the array when the values are needed.